# How to use 'Overwrite web layer' without popup in arcgis pro

Tags: arcgis

Currently when you use "Overwrite Web Layer" for example in a task, it shows a file popup to select the layer from disk.  This is very annoying when adding this command to a task where a layer already exists in the current map, no need to go to disk!  I would like this command to work the same as "Publish Web Layer" where it lets you select the existing layer from the map.  How can I do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the answer.  The answer is that this is currently a limitation of ArcGIS Pro.  The "Publish Web Layer" is Model-Builder ready but the "Overwrite Web Layer" is not Model-Builder ready yet.  (So you have the annoying pop-up window to go to disk to select layer).  Hopefully this will be corrected in future versions of ArcGIS pro.